# Microsoft webbrowser FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION in RDP application

Tags: webbrowser-control, rdp

I have an application that has an embedded Microsoft webbrowser ActiveX control.  On the server where the application is installed - it runs fine (runs quickly, runs scripts) within the application.  The application is exposed via RDP for users to run - the Microsoft webbrowser ActiveX control page does not work properly (hangs for a long time - finally displays script error message - scripts don't work) when it is run using an RDP session.

When directly accessed from any computer, the webpage that is contained in the ActiveX control runs fine.

The application.exe files are in these registry folders with the appropriate decimal value (11001):
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION

I'm thinking that there is something more that I need to do to either force the version emulation or permit scripts.

Server is 2012R2 64-bit OS

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure client browsers are supporting ActiveX
2. Set sufficient permissions for clients [Explained Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17469/)
3. Change Security Layer and User Authentication to a hexadecimal 0 in

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal
>   Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp

You can do this via Regedit

4. Reboot the server

Comment: Thanks - the ActiveX controls are OK...the page works fine locally.  There aren't any ActiveX controls in the page itself - the application has an ActiveX Microsoft webbrowser object.  I updated the registry as suggested and rebooted - no change.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Internet Explorer on the server was pointing to an old proxy server that was likely finally removed from service.  I updated the proxy server to the one that is used by the clients and it works fine.